# C/C++ arrays assignment

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization, variable-assignment

Sample code:

```
int ar[3];
............
ar[0] = 123;
ar[1] = 456;
ar[2] = 789;
```

Is there any way to init it shorter? Something like:

```
int ar[3];
............
ar[] = { 123, 456, 789 };
```

I don't need solution like:

```
int ar[] = { 123, 456, 789 };
```

Definition and initialization must be separate.

Comment: Terminology: Initialization is giving a value at the moment of definition. What you want is "array assignment".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done directly. There are, however different things that you can do there, starting from creation of a local array initialized with the aggregate initialization and then `memcpy`-ed over your array (valid only for POD types), or using higher level libraries like `boost::assign`.

```
// option1
int array[10];
//... code
{
   int tmp[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
   memcpy( array, tmp, sizeof array ); // ! beware of both array sizes here!!
}  // end of local scope, tmp should go away and compiler can reclaim stack space
```

I don't have time to check how to do this with `boost::assign`, as I hardly ever work with raw arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought that exists some way in this language or in compiler extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be assigned directly:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Check the [C++ Arrays tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), too.

Comment: I don't need initialization after definion of array. I need to init array deeper in the code.

Comment: @archer: then why can't you define it at the point you need it to be initialized?

Comment: This point located in the loop. Maybe im mistaken, but with huge amount of loop executes will be more optimized to define array out of this loop.

Comment: You can assign it in the same way: `a = {1, 2, 3}`. But that's actually C++0x ("extended initializer lists"). If you need to reassign the array in each loop iteration, you can still use `memcpy`.

Comment: @archer: then you're almost surely wrong. Array allocation on the stack in just a stack pointer addition/subtraction. The compiler may optimize and allocate it in function's stackframe just like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

int a[] = {1,2,3};

this doesn't work for you?

```
main()
{
    int a[] = {1,3,2};

    printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    printf("Size: %d\n", (sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)));

}
```

prints:

```
1 3 2
Size: 3
```

Comment: Microsoft C++ (VS2010). You are using initialization after definition. I need separate.

Comment: `main` with no return type!? What compiler are you using!?

Comment: @ybungalobill: gcc 3.3.5 but the point was not the main but the array use, just put it up quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[3];
    arr[0] = 123, arr[1] = 345, arr[2] = 567;
    printf("%d,%d,%d", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the C99 array initialization?

```
int array[] = {
   [0] = 5, // array[0] = 5
   [3] = 8, // array[3] = 8
   [255] = 9, // array[255] = 9
};
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, but we're not discussing initialization :)